# Unspecified error trying to connect to SqlServer CE 4.0 from classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-ce, adodb

I am trying to get some old ASP page to use new data source. The following code

```
var cn = Server.createObject("adodb.connection");
var cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.mapPath("employees.sdf");
Response.write(cnString); // for debug only
cn.open(cnString);
```

throws "80004005 Unspecified error" on the last line. The SqlServer Compact 4.0 is obviously installed on the machine I am trying to run this on. I am able to connect to this db using SQL Management Studio just fine. The path in `Data Source=` is correct. I also gave `Everyone`  full permission to the folder where the file resides just in case.

Not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some access denied error, could you try with a full path instead - see http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/access-sql-server-compact-4-with-asp.html - you could use ProcMon from Sysinternals to check if it is an access denied error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since then I downgraded to provider 3.5 and that worked fine. Unfortunately I can't spend any more time to try to debug it with ProcMon.